# sonarqube runs and stops after while for no apparent reason

Tags: sonarqube

First of all: on my RHEL system I installed Sonarqube 4.2 with a MS SQL Server 2008R2 database.

The service is started and running and then stopped after a while, so when i try to access the Sonarqube-service in my webbrowser the url is not accessible. In the logfile everything looks ok, but it is stopping. I installed the latest jTDS JDBC driver, but that didn't succeed too. I checked in the db if TCP/IP on port 1433 is enabled, but that's ok.

This is the output in the sonar.log:

```
Launching a JVM... Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

2014.04.08 16:13:44 INFO  [o.s.a.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 8082
2014.04.08 16:13:45 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8082"]
2014.04.08 16:13:45 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardService]  Starting service Tomcat
2014.04.08 16:13:45 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardEngine]  Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014.04.08 16:13:45 INFO  [o.a.c.s.ContextConfig]  No global web.xml found
2014.04.08 16:13:46 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:46 INFO  [o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<sonarserver>;databaseName=SONAR42;SelectMethod=Cursor;
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  Deploy dir: /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins...
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Maven Batch Plugin / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Surefire / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Duplications / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Core / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Java / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin English Pack / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Design / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins done: 111 ms
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ApplicationDeployer]  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Start components...
2014.04.08 16:13:48 INFO  [o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector]  Initializing Hibernate
2014.04.08 16:13:49 INFO  [o.s.s.es.ESIndex]  Starting Elasticsearch...
2014.04.08 16:13:49 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] version[0.90.9], pid[29018], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
2014.04.08 16:13:49 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initializing ...
2014.04.08 16:13:51 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initialized
2014.04.08 16:13:51 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] starting ...
2014.04.08 16:13:51 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] started
2014.04.08 16:13:54 INFO  [o.s.s.es.ESIndex]  Elasticsearch started
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient]  Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (proxy: proxy.pr.lan:8888)
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Code colorizer, supported languages: java
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy GWT plugins...
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.libraries.LibrariesPage to /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy/gwt
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.page.DesignPage to /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy/gwt
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy GWT plugins done: 28 ms
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Load metrics...
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics]  cleaning alert thresholds...
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Load metrics done: 367 ms
2014.04.08 16:13:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules...
2014.04.08 16:13:56 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Build rules documents...
2014.04.08 16:13:56 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Build rules documents done: 169 ms
2014.04.08 16:13:56 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Index rules...
2014.04.08 16:13:57 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Index rules done: 1017 ms
2014.04.08 16:13:58 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules done: 2594 ms
2014.04.08 16:13:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewProfiles]  Register Quality Profiles...
2014.04.08 16:44:00 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformLifecycleListener]  Fail to start server
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection reset
### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.template.LoadedTemplateMapper
### The error may involve org.sonar.core.template.LoadedTemplateMapper.countByTypeAndKey
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection reset
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:107) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.countByTypeAndKey(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.core.template.LoadedTemplateDao.countByTypeAndKey(LoadedTemplateDao.java:39) ~[sonar-core-4.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.startup.RegisterNewProfiles.shouldRegister(RegisterNewProfiles.java:133) ~[RegisterNewProfiles.class:na]
        at org.sonar.server.startup.RegisterNewProfiles.start(RegisterNewProfiles.java:101) ~[RegisterNewProfiles.class:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:433) ~[Platform.class:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:176) ~[Platform.class:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:54) ~[PlatformLifecycleListener.class:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection reset
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148) ~[commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:131) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:58) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:271) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.prepareStatement(ReuseExecutor.java:72) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:53) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:259) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:132) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:125) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:460) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        ... 50 common frames omitted
2014.04.08 16:44:05 INFO  [o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service stopped
2014.04.08 16:44:05 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] stopping ...
2014.04.08 16:44:05 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] stopped
2014.04.08 16:44:05 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] closing ...
2014.04.08 16:44:05 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] closed
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Please, is there anyone who can help me?

My sonar.properties is listed below:

```
#----- Microsoft SQLServer
# The Jtds open source driver is available in extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql. More details on http://jtds.sourceforge.net
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<sonarserver>;databaseName=SONAR42;SelectMethod=Cursor;
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1
#----- Connection pool settings
sonar.jdbc.username=<username>
sonar.jdbc.password=<password>
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=10
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
sonar.web.context=/

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=8082

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# The Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
#sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
http.proxyHost=proxy.pr.lan
http.proxyPort=8888

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
socksProxyHost=proxy.pr.lan
socksProxyPort=8888



2014.04.08 20:09:41 INFO  [o.s.a.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 8082
2014.04.08 20:09:41 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-172.30.72.255-8082"]
2014.04.08 20:09:41 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardService]  Starting service Tomcat
2014.04.08 20:09:41 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardEngine]  Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014.04.08 20:09:42 INFO  [o.a.c.s.ContextConfig]  No global web.xml found
2014.04.08 20:09:43 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:43 INFO  [o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<sonarserver>;databaseName=SONAR42;SelectMethod=Cursor
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  Deploy dir: /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins...
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Maven Batch Plugin / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Surefire / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Duplications / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Core / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Java / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin English Pack / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 2.1 / c67e33acdf1a04bfafe9f4ff971182178cdd7ae3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Design / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 4.2 / bdbd9d27938ea150194c0d3cdcc8bbe31a419bd3
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins done: 107 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:44 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ApplicationDeployer]  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2014.04.08 20:09:45 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Start components...
2014.04.08 20:09:45 INFO  [o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector]  Initializing Hibernate
2014.04.08 20:09:46 INFO  [o.s.s.es.ESIndex]  Starting Elasticsearch...
2014.04.08 20:09:46 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] version[0.90.9], pid[32395], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
2014.04.08 20:09:46 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initializing ...
2014.04.08 20:09:48 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initialized
2014.04.08 20:09:48 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] starting ...
2014.04.08 20:09:48 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] started
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [o.s.s.es.ESIndex]  Elasticsearch started
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient]  Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Code colorizer, supported languages: java
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy GWT plugins...
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.libraries.LibrariesPage to /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy/gwt
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.page.DesignPage to /data/sonar/sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy/gwt
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy GWT plugins done: 27 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:51 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Load metrics...
2014.04.08 20:09:52 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics]  cleaning alert thresholds...
2014.04.08 20:09:52 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Load metrics done: 475 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:52 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules...
2014.04.08 20:09:53 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Build rules documents...
2014.04.08 20:09:53 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Build rules documents done: 160 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:53 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Index rules...
2014.04.08 20:09:54 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Index rules done: 969 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:54 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules done: 2594 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:54 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewProfiles]  Register Quality Profiles...
2014.04.08 20:09:56 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewProfiles]  Register Quality Profiles done: 2031 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:57 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Remove deleted active rule documents...
2014.04.08 20:09:57 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Remove deleted active rule documents done: 1 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:57 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterTechnicalDebtModel]  Register Technical Debt Model...
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterTechnicalDebtModel]  Register Technical Debt Model done: 542 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters]  Register measure filters...
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters]  Register measure filters done: 5 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewDashboards]  Register dashboards...
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterNewDashboards]  Register dashboards done: 32 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates]  Register permission templates...
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates]  Register permission templates done: 2 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys]  Rename deprecated property keys
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Start components done: 13436 ms
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51-mockbuild_2014_01_10_10_19-b00 [linux-amd64]
2014.04.08 20:09:58 INFO  [jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2014.04.08 20:10:12 INFO  [jruby.rack]  keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2014.04.08 20:10:12 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-172.30.72.255-8082"]
2014.04.08 20:10:12 INFO  Web server is started
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include these jdbc connection pool propterties:

```
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery=select 1
sonar.jdbc.dialect=mssql
```

Here are all my properties for reference :

```
sonar.jdbc.username=Sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=Secret
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://dbserver;databaseName=SonarQube;selectMethod=cursor;
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery=select 1
sonar.jdbc.dialect=mssql
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
http.proxyHost=webgatewayproxy
http.proxyPort=9090
http.proxyUser=user
http.proxyPassword=pass
```

Note: I do not have any sonar.web properties, I just use the defaults. This works fine with:

- Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008
- A simple http proxy

Comment: As you can see Cole i already added your text in sonar.properties.

Comment: @user have you tried using an `=` like all of your other properties, instead of the `:`

Comment: i changed this, but it has the same result.

Comment: @user Do you use proxy authentication? Might wanna specify `http.proxyUser=user` and `http.proxyPassword=pass` .. I would also try this property to see if anything changes : `sonar.jdbc.dialect=mssql`

Comment: The string with mssql dialect is added. The proxy settings i copied from an old instance of Sonar 2.11 on a Ubuntu 32 bits server. On that server proxy authentication was inactive also. But i commented out the proxy settings   'code'# HTTP proxy (default none)
#http.proxyHost=proxy.pr.lan
#http.proxyPort=8888

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=proxy.pr.lan
#socksProxyPort=8888

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=   'code'.

Comment: Just i listed the new sonar.log. The service is still running, but i can't access Sonar in the webbrowser. I don't know what the user and password are when i use proxy authentication.

Comment: Is it important to enable 'sonar.web.host' or is ok to disable this?

Comment: that property doesnt matter if your using `http://sonarserver:8082` (specifying ports). Your log indicates everything started successfully, you should be good to go.

Comment: Dude you might wanna clean up your post you just gave us your database and server IP

Comment: yes, but unfortunately when i use sonarserver:8082 i still get connection has timed out in the browser.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the server from the server? Because in that case you would need to use `http://localhost:8082`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning, i cleaned up my post. I navigated to localhost, but still there is nothing:(.

Comment: What's your access.log say? any entries about you trying to navigate to the url?

Comment: The access.log is empty.

Comment: That indicates there's something wrong with your `sonar.web` properties. Probably because `sonar.web.context=/` ... just comment out that property and restart the service, try again..

Comment: Still access.log is empty.

Comment: Ufortunately i'll have stop Cole. Tomorrow i'll try again an again :). Thank you Cole.